# Is there a way to execute a function in parallel other than apply or foreach?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, parallel.foreach, doparallel

So for my first post I came up with quite an embarassing problem. I have this code written in R which is basically a for loop analysis on X number of genes to get outputs written in 4 different files.
The problem is, it is taking way, way too long. And the idea here was trying to use the full calculation power of the cluster I'm working on and spread up the loop on different cores.

The main function is structured like this :

- opening the input datas in different dataframes, shaping and creating variables like number of samples and genes (which are used later in the output files creation and the main `for` loop)
- setting a seed
- creating all the output files where the results will be written in
- the main loop for the analysis that will iterate for all genes doing the calculation and writing results each time.

So to speed up this, I was thinking of spliting my gene dataframe of let say 500 genes in smaller subsets of 20 genes each and running the main loop for each of them in parallel. The problem, from what I understood reading about `foreach` and `mcapply` for example is that they are more designed for multiple iterations on the same dataset and not using the same function on different datasets. I might be wrong.

The other solution would be to run multiple genes at the same time, but I can't figure out the way to do that.

I am sorry for the long post and also that I can't provide code... But I'll be happy to precise a bit if there are some ideas or suggested solutions.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please provide a working example of your code and some data.

Comment: Hi,  the data I'm using is personal so I can't share... and the pipeline is quite long actually to be paste here.
For an easier reading this is the github where the code is comming from, the files used here are gtex_tiss_chrom_training.R and gtex_v7_nested_cv_elnet.R . The first one is calling functions written in the second one.
https://github.com/hakyimlab/PredictDB_Pipeline_GTEx_v7/tree/master/model_training/scripts

Answer (score 1):

I think library "parallel" will help you here.  You can use mclapply function, which is similar to lapply, but distributes the tasks to multiple processors and consolidates the responses from each of these function calls and returns.
An example:

```
library(parallel)
nC <- detectCores()

mclapply(your_data, your_function, nC)
```

Comment: The problem I have with this is that my input data is multiple, does it works for several input files? 
My main function call looks like this : 
`main(snp_annot_file, gene_annot_file, genotype_file, expression_file, covariates_file, as.numeric(chrom), prefix, null_testing=FALSE)`